# SAS: keep format when merging

Tags: merge, sas, format

I am trying to merge three data(A1, A2, A3) with different formats. The datasets are all just simple one-row two-column datasets. However, once I merge them, the format style disappears and shows the format of data A1. Does anyone know how to keep the format when merging?

```
DATA A1;
FORMAT _NUMERIC_ 7.1;
RUN;

DATA A2;
SET A0;
RUN;

DATA A3;
FORMAT a b PERCENT7.1;
RUN;

DATA A4; SET A1 A2 A3;
RUN;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is in data set `A0` ?

Comment: I don't understand what your issue is nor what your example is trying to show.  Your A1 dataset has no variables.  Formats are attached to variables not observations.

Answer (score 0):

The (Program Data Vector) PDV is the storage assembly constructed by the implicit and automatic compile/run operation performed by the SAS executor.

Each item in the PDV corresponds to a variable and its attendant metadata (type, length, format, informat, label, etc...)

The variables in the data sets called out in a SET statement are automatically added to the PDV (along with the variables metadata).  Once an item is in the PDV, later data sets in the same SET statement will NOT overwrite existing PDV items.

Your sample code is a bit flawed because A1 has no variables, A2 step has an error and A3 is ok.  The A4 variables will inherit the A3 metadata because of this flawness.

Per your SET statement, suppose A1 has a variable X, then X in data set A4 would inherit the A1.X metadata.

Comment: Too simplistic an explanation for FORMAT/INFORMAT assignment.  SAS will choose the first non empty format, even if it is not from the first dataset that has the variable.

Comment: Certainly is. The "A few good men" memorable quote comically entered my cranium as  Yek, "you can't handle the truth" (yet)

Answer (score 0):

FORMATS are attached to variables, not observations. So you cannot have both `7.1` and `PERCENT7.1` attached to the variable A in the dataset A4.  One variable can only have one format permanently attached to it.  But note that it does not have to have any format permanently attached to it.

When you combine datasets that have variables in common SAS will define the variable (that is set the variable's **type** and **length**) based on how it is defined in the first dataset being combined that contains that variable.

For other variable attributes (FORMAT, INFORMAT, LABEL) it is a little more complex.  Those will be set to the first non-empty value that is seen for the variable, even if that is not the first time the variable is seen.  And those attributes of the variable can be overridden by explicit assignments in the data step.  For numeric variables you can even override the LENGTH attribute for the variable since it only applies to how the variable is stored in the output dataset.